# Small Data Frame Causes R to Crash

Tags: r, dataframe, crash, rstudio

I have a list of (grouped) data.frames which all have 1 or 2 rows and which all have the same columns.  Two of the data frames work perfectly fine as expected.  However, expressing the third data frame to the console or manipulating it in any way will cause R to crash.  In some R studio environments I am not even able to load the data using readRDS().  Is there some possibility that the third data contains some embedded data?  If so how could I inspect it? It is not really possible to reproduce an example, so I have uploaded the small data set to filedropper here:

https://www.filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=0c7cbfc10bc788e4515814748c96399b

```
> library(dplyr)
> 
> df_list <- readRDS(file = "C:\\Users\\crist\\Desktop\\dataframe_list.rds")
> 
> df_list[[1]] %>% ungroup() %>% class()
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> df_list[[1]] %>% ungroup() %>% colnames()
 [1] "leg.id"            "arb_identifier"    "SecurityID"        "date"              "UnderlyingClose"   "UnderlyingOpen"   
 [7] "TotalReturn"       "ReferenceExchange" "OptionID"          "Expiration"        "CallPut"           "Strike"           
[13] "Volume"            "OpenInterest"      "ImpliedVolatility" "Delta"             "Gamma"             "Vega"             
[19] "Theta"             "AdjustmentFactor"  "BestBid"           "BestOffer"         "Last"              "LastTradeDate"    
[25] "T"                 "stale"             "old"               "roll"              "n_opt_shares"      "delta.hedge"      
[31] "OrigBid"           "OrigOffer"         "PXRecov"           "acquisition_date"  "tranche_id"       
> df_list[[1]] %>% ungroup() %>% NROW()
[1] 1
> df_list[[1]] %>% ungroup()%>% data.frame()
           leg.id arb_identifier SecurityID       date UnderlyingClose UnderlyingOpen TotalReturn ReferenceExchange  OptionID Expiration
1 L_P_OTM5.0_93_0              1     506528 2005-12-19          5539.8         5531.6 0.001482339               -99 150042133 2006-01-20
  CallPut        Strike        Volume OpenInterest ImpliedVolatility       Delta        Gamma     Vega     Theta AdjustmentFactor BestBid
1       P 2.581493e-320 8.685674e-321        16674         0.1386455 -0.06867341 0.0005814221 216.8916 -164.2587                0       7
  BestOffer Last LastTradeDate       T stale   old  roll n_opt_shares delta.hedge OrigBid OrigOffer PXRecov acquisition_date tranche_id
1         7    7          <NA> 32 days FALSE FALSE FALSE         2499         Inf      35        35     0.2       2005-10-03    9381673
> 
> df_list[[2]] %>% ungroup() %>% class()
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> df_list[[2]] %>% ungroup() %>% colnames()
 [1] "leg.id"            "arb_identifier"    "SecurityID"        "date"              "UnderlyingClose"   "UnderlyingOpen"   
 [7] "TotalReturn"       "ReferenceExchange" "OptionID"          "Expiration"        "CallPut"           "Strike"           
[13] "Volume"            "OpenInterest"      "ImpliedVolatility" "Delta"             "Gamma"             "Vega"             
[19] "Theta"             "AdjustmentFactor"  "BestBid"           "BestOffer"         "Last"              "LastTradeDate"    
[25] "T"                 "stale"             "old"               "roll"              "n_opt_shares"      "delta.hedge"      
[31] "OrigBid"           "OrigOffer"         "PXRecov"           "acquisition_date"  "tranche_id"       
> df_list[[2]] %>% ungroup() %>% NROW()
[1] 1
> df_list[[2]] %>% ungroup()%>% data.frame()
           leg.id arb_identifier SecurityID       date UnderlyingClose UnderlyingOpen TotalReturn ReferenceExchange  OptionID Expiration
1 L_P_OTM5.0_93_0              1     506528 2005-12-20          5547.9         5539.8 0.001462164               -99 150042133 2006-01-20
  CallPut        Strike        Volume OpenInterest ImpliedVolatility      Delta        Gamma     Vega     Theta AdjustmentFactor BestBid
1       P 2.581493e-320 1.167971e-320        17155         0.1427761 -0.0636712 0.0005403475 201.6763 -158.4806                0     6.5
  BestOffer Last LastTradeDate       T stale   old  roll n_opt_shares delta.hedge OrigBid OrigOffer   PXRecov acquisition_date tranche_id
1       6.5  6.5          <NA> 31 days FALSE FALSE FALSE         2499         Inf      35        35 0.1857143       2005-10-03    9381673
> 
> df_list[[3]] %>% ungroup() %>% class()
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> df_list[[3]] %>% ungroup() %>% colnames()
 [1] "leg.id"            "arb_identifier"    "SecurityID"        "date"              "UnderlyingClose"   "UnderlyingOpen"   
 [7] "TotalReturn"       "ReferenceExchange" "OptionID"          "Expiration"        "CallPut"           "Strike"           
[13] "Volume"            "OpenInterest"      "ImpliedVolatility" "Delta"             "Gamma"             "Vega"             
[19] "Theta"             "AdjustmentFactor"  "BestBid"           "BestOffer"         "Last"              "LastTradeDate"    
[25] "T"                 "stale"             "old"               "roll"              "n_opt_shares"      "delta.hedge"      
[31] "OrigBid"           "OrigOffer"         "PXRecov"           "acquisition_date"  "tranche_id"       
> df_list[[3]] %>% ungroup() %>% NROW()
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is broken in that file, but I can reproduce this in linux. I've been able to avoid it (and only lose two columns of data) by removing columns 12-13:

```r
as.data.frame(df_list[[1]]) # no problem
as.data.frame(df_list[[2]]) # no problem
as.data.frame(df_list[[3]])[-(12:13)]
#            leg.id arb_identifier SecurityID       date UnderlyingClose
# 1 L_P_OTM5.0_93_0              1     506528 2005-12-21          5587.4
#   UnderlyingOpen TotalReturn ReferenceExchange  OptionID Expiration CallPut
# 1         5547.9 0.007119811               -99 150042133 2006-01-20       P
#   OpenInterest ImpliedVolatility       Delta        Gamma     Vega     Theta
# 1        18051         0.1430592 -0.04223828 0.0003929387 144.2409 -117.1857
#   AdjustmentFactor BestBid BestOffer Last LastTradeDate       T stale   old
# 1                0       4         4    4          <NA> 30 days FALSE FALSE
#    roll n_opt_shares delta.hedge OrigBid OrigOffer   PXRecov acquisition_date
# 1 FALSE         2499         Inf      35        35 0.1142857       2005-10-03
#   tranche_id
# 1    9381673
```

My guess is that the file itself is corrupted somehow (I don't know enough about the internal RDS structure to deep-dive it), and columns 12-13 (`Strike` and `Volume`) are causing the problem. (If you can live without or regenerate those two values from the third frame, then you should be able to move on.)

Comment: any luck with your issue, quantyquanty?